# CakePHP 1.3 migration To 4.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3

Hello I need Some Help ,
I Have a CakePhP Project in version 1.3. I want To migrate in to 4.x is it possible and can anyone Help
what are the steps to follow to migrate from 1.3 to 4.1 CakePhp version

Comment: It's very complicated to upgrade from 1.3 to 4.0. You should find someone or some company to do this.

Answer (score 3):

1. create a new php 7.4 / MySql work environment (using docker, vagrant, xampp,..)
2. export database from current app
3. import database to new environment
4. init new cakephp 4 app
5. connect cakephp 4 to database
6. bake basic MVC app
7. look at cakephp 1.3 template and create same representations at new app
8. look at old controllers actions and create new in cakephp 4 way
9. look at old models methods and create new in cakephp 4 way
10. update routings
11. copy assets

This is a simplified guide to migrating from your web application based on the old version of cakephp to the latest version.